# Is it possible to manipulate some text with an user-defined I/O manipulator?

Tags: c++

Is there a (clean) way to manipulate some text from std::cin before inserting it into a `std::string`, so that the following would work:

```
cin >> setw(80) >> Uppercase >> mystring;
```

where mystring is `std::string` (I don't want to use any wrappers for strings).
`Uppercase` is a manipulator. I think it needs to act on the Chars in the buffer directly (no matter what is considered uppercase rather than lowercase now). Such a manipulator seems difficult to implement in a clean way, as user-defined manipulators, as far as I know, are used to just change or mix some pre-determined format flags easily.

Comment: Related but not identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391746/how-to-easily-indent-output-to-ofstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Non-extended) manipulators usually only set flags and data which the extractors afterwards read and react to. (That is what `xalloc`, `iword`, and `pword` are for.) What you could, obviously, do, is to write something analogous to `std::get_money`:

```
struct uppercasify {
  uppercasify(std::string &s) : ref(s) {}
  uppercasify(const uppercasify &other) : ref(other.ref) {}
  std::string &ref;
}
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, uppercasify uc) { // or &&uc in C++11
  is >> uc.ref;
  boost::to_upper(uc.ref);
  return is;
}

cin >> setw(80) >> uppercasify(mystring);
```

Alternatively, `cin >> uppercase` could return not a reference to `cin`, but an instantiation of some (template) wrapper class `uppercase_istream`, with the corresponding overload for `operator>>`. I don't think having a manipulator modify the underlying stream buffer's contents is a good idea.

If you're desperate enough, I guess you could also `imbue` a hand-crafted locale resulting in uppercasing strings. I don't think I'd let anything like that go through a code review, though – it's simply just waiting to surprise and bite the next person working on the code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Maybe you meant to say std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, const uppercasify &uc) since uppercasify(mystring) is a temporary object

Comment: It can't work with `const`, since the code uses non-`const` operations on `uc.ref`. Drop the `&` or use C++11 and use `&&`. But Anon's pointer to boost is probably what I'd follow anyway.

Comment: sorry if I insist, but ref is a reference, not a const reference, so non-const operations should be fine on ref even with a const uppercasify& , shouldn't they? My gcc compiler compiles the above code only if I use a const uppercasify& for operator >> (c++ 98 here)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that “inheriting” cv-qualifiers does not apply to reference types. (§3.9.3/3, if anyone wants to look it up.) You're right.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out boost iostreams.  Its framework allows defining filters which can manipulate the stream.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html