# make std::ostream automatically ident when encountering special characters

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, ostream

I would like to have some facility which makes a `std::ostream` (or derived) automatically ident on encountering special characters (or special objects). Let's assume that the special characters are `<` and `>`. In this case the following input `test0<test1<test2, test3<test4> > >` should produce the following output:

```
test0<
    test1<
        test2,
        test3<
            test4
        >
    >
>
```

How would one go to implement this?

Comment: should it detect those characters by itself or indent should be forced by call of some function? Is it enough  to change behavior when single character is output on stream?

Comment: @MarekR The only restriction is that normal formatting of std::ostream should continue working.

Comment: [boost iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/filtering_streams.html) might help

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397588/14065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[boost::iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iostreams/doc/) makes this fairly easy, you can define filters then chain them together with an output stream to transform the input to the desired output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

struct QuoteOutputFilter {
  typedef char                   char_type;
  typedef io::output_filter_tag  category;

  int indent = 0;

  template<typename Sink>
  bool newLine(Sink& snk)
  {
    std::string str = "\n" + std::string(indent * 4, ' ');
    return io::write(snk, str.c_str(), str.size());
  }

  template<typename Sink>
  bool put(Sink& snk, char c)
  {
    switch (c)
    {
      case '<':
        io::put(snk, c);
        indent += 1;
        return newLine(snk);
      case ',':
        io::put(snk, c);
        return newLine(snk);
      case '>':
        indent -= 1;
        newLine(snk);
        return io::put(snk, c);
      default:
        return io::put(snk, c);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  io::filtering_ostream out;
  out.push(QuoteOutputFilter());
  out.push(std::cout);

  out << "test0<test1<test2, test3<test4> > >";
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see in the boost sources, the newLine() method is not called from the outside. Does it need to have a bool return type?

Comment: It needs to return the value of `io::write` via `put`

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream`? The IOStream design is rather complicated (and a tad slow), so I can see why you'd think this. The name `ostream` sounds like a good hint, but it really doesn't do much. It really works by binding `std::ostreambuf` and `operator<<` overloads together. The derived `ostream` classes provide concrete streambufs.

What you'd want is likely a `streambuf` filter. You grab the underlying streambuf, and use that as an output, but you insert some extra spaces when you see a `>`